Запрет одновременного редактирования сущности БД
Какой подход вы используете, когда нужно, чтобы в один и тот же момент одну сущность(любая таблица) бд мог редактировать один пользователь.

Раньше я криво-косо реализовывал блокировку через bool переменную, когда кто-то открывал запись и ее закрывал. Работало, но при запуске сервера приходилось обнулять все такие поля, что считаю плохой практикой. Сейчас бы, наверное, реализовал это через Redis, но тоже не до конца понимаю этого.

CAS(compare and swap) - хранение версии сущности и затем ее сверка, когда клиент хочет обновить ее. Мне нравится идея, но не нравится то, что при сохранении пользователь может обнаружить, что его версия устарела и он не может сохранить данные. Тут либо ему перезагрузить все введенные данные или же рядом во вкладке показать новые данные. В общем, на мой взгляд достаточно сложно сделать удобно с точки зрения UI/UX особенно, когда он вводил с десяток полей на форме.


Пример то, как я это представляю в голове:

Пользователь A открыл запись и редактирует ее. На ограниченное время или нет, я не знаю, но пусть будет 15 минут.
Пользователь B пытается открыть ту же запись и получает уведомление, что сейчас ее редактирует пользователь А и ее можно открыть только в режиме чтения.
Если ограничение на редактирование есть, а я думаю оно необходимо, то спустя это время пользователь А теряет возможность сохранения в бд и ему нужно перезагрузить страницу редактирования. Может быть неудобно, но пока так)

P.S Теги условные, но стек - C# WPF/Avalonia.

Можно это реализовывать силами самой СУБД - вешать физическую блокировку записи, можно делать логическую блокировку - в сущность добавить поле "isUpdating" и проверять. Не знаю, какую СУБД используете вы, например oracle позволяет заблокировать запись так select * from table for update where id = 1 а при отборе записей на редактирование делать так select * from table for update where id = 1 skip locked - такой запрос вернет только не заблокированные записи

Эти два способа называются пессимистичная и оптимистичная блокировки (pessimistic и optimistic locking). По этим терминам можете найти подробные описания. Причём они поддерживаются большинством СУБД.

@AlexanderPetrov спасибо. Я уже и забыл их название)

Прочитайте документацию от производителя:
Сайт Microsoft - SQL Server - Уровни изоляции транзакций (выберите нужную версию SQL Server'a)
Dapper
Если вы иcпользуете Dapper Framework для доступа к БД,
то там все уровни изоляций к БД пишутся на языке SQL версии БД.
Если вы используете Entity Framework,
то почитайте бесплатную книгу по синхронизации потоков на этом фреймворке:
Параллелизм в EF Core
Полная книга, по EF Core:
EF Core
PS.: Если Вам не удобно читать документацию от носителей языка,
то Вы можете пользоваться онлайн переводчиком, то можно переводить страницы онлайн, но постранично:
Google Переведи
Яндекс переводчик

Спасибо за ответ. Metanit почитал. Полезно! Но если мне кроме просто ошибки нужно вывести допустим имя другого пользователя(тот кто заблокировал редактирование), то как это сделать? Вручную я бы смог точно также хранить версию и id другого пользователя, но как этого добиться с ConcurrencyCheck? Если я в сущность добавлю id пользователя кто ее блокирует, то у нее уже автоматически поменяется же версия, если у нее флаг ConcurrencyCheck? Я думаю есть готовые решиня без велосипеда.

@Lapish - готовые решения если и есть, то они привязаны к конкретной СУБД. Поэтому нужно выбрать какую-то СУБД (Postgres, MySql, etc) и указать её в метках вопроса. / В ORM могут быть средства упрощающие работы с блокировками, но сомневаюсь, что может быть общий механизм получения имени пользователя, держащего блокировку.

@Lapish, нужно сделать чтобы только один пользователь мог редактировать запись одновременно, второму вывод ошибки  типа "запись не возможена". Скорее всего не правильно производить доступ к нескольких учёткок на изменение данных записи одновременно, или второму обнолять страницу со словами запись изменили и сохранить собственную превьюшку (к примеру html-страницы). Если доступ по учётке, то один и тот же пользователь врят ли сидит на двух устройствах одновременно.
